# Exchange 2010 mailboxDabasecopyStatus * service down

Tags: exchange

Today i tried creating a new mailbox on my exchange 2010 multitenant sever.
The mailbox creation failed with error

"Load balancing failed to find a valid mailbox database."

After some research on the internet i ran the command

```
Get-MailboxDatabaseCopyStatus *
```

This shows the mailbox database status as service down. i am assuming this to be the cause of the error when it should be status mounted.

how can i change this status to mounted.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the `Microsoft Exchange Information Store` service is running? Have you tried to mount the database?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if you can [manually mount the database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123587(v=exchg.141).aspx) or not. If not, the database might be in a dirty shutdown status, which need to be repaired.

You can refer to this blog for recover database which is in a dirty shutdown status: http://msexchangeguru.com/2009/07/12/exchange-database-recovery-using-eseutil-commands/