# Exchange can't connect to the Information Store service on server ---.------.com

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

I have exchange multitenant i get the following error`Exchange can't connect to the Information Store service on server ---.------.com` when running `Get-MailboxDatabase -Identity "mydb" -Status` the microsoft exchange information store service is running so why am i getting this error and how can this be resolve

Thanks

Rehan Miah

Comment: From where did you got that error? Are you directly on the affected Exchange server?

Comment: You asked a very similar question here: https://serverfault.com/questions/852672/exchange-2010-mailboxdabasecopystatus-service-down. What have you done to troubleshoot this? What steps have you taken? What's in the event l,ogs? You've not given us much information to work with.

Comment: My exchange server is clustered where i have cas and ht running on one server and mailbox role running on the other server. it is a multitenant install  of exchange 2010. I get this error when running the above command on the server with the mailbox role installed